# React Router 4 Optional Path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Desktop}/>
          <Route path='/OrdersView(&filters=:filters)' component={OrdersView}/>                               
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('application')
);
```

How write optional path in  router v4? like this

```
<Route path='/OrdersView(&filters=:filters)' component={OrdersView}/>
```

For the one component {OrderView}.
I should be able to receive URLs in two versions:

```
http://..../OrderView
http://..../OrderView&filters={"a":"1"}
```

I tried to write

```
<Route path='/OrdersView?.+' component={OrdersView}/>
```

but nothing

I suppose the problem is because I'm using

```
this.props.location.query.filter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/roster' component={FullRoster}/>
    <Route path='/roster/:number' component={Player}/>
</Switch>
```

It's gotten from https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf. Here is quite nice explanations for 4th version of routes.